# Displaying a chart using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I'm pretty new to javaScript. I'm trying to get good hold over interactive charts and stuff. For that I downloaded HighCharts library... can't find any appropriate way to use it to print the graph.. tried some examples but none of them is working. I'm currently here:

```
<body>

<script src="../../../Downloads/Highcharts JS/js/highcharts.js">
context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
context.fillRect(10,10,100,100);

var chart1 = new HighCharts.chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'graphDiv',
         defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
         text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
         categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
         }
      },
      series: [{
         name: 'Anne',
         data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
         name: 'Martin',
         data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
   });

</script>
</body>
```

I think I'm missing some libraries or this isn't the right way to include libraries in javascript? Kindly guide me through printing this graph..

Comment: you should add jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'graphDiv',
         defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
         text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
         categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
         }
      },
      series: [{
         name: 'Anne',
         data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
         name: 'Martin',
         data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
   });
});
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7D3em/

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not sure. The thing is that Highcharts already use canvas to display the graphs. Why would you do that ?

Comment: actually im trying to make a web application in which user can draw charts and graphs by just clicking on the icon and then clicking inside the cnavas, chart should be drawn on that location (data will be provided by user in a file)

Comment: You can do it with a div the same way don't you ? You have to draw the chart on the div the user clicked with the file the user choosed.

Comment: yea.. but i'm offering a paint application as well, so it has to be canvas. i found this other library 'chart.js' i think that's the solution to my problem. thanks for your help

Comment: In this case you are right you are better off with chart.js if you want to dig more into the code. Moreover it's free which is not the case with HighCharts. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach jquery and add div with id "graphDiv" where chart will be printed.